# Can just opening email infect Mac in any way?

Tags: email, malware

I'd like opinion on this:

If I open email and see text, can it infect my Mac? Not opening attachments, just email itself. Can that be dangerous? I delete all suspicious and unknown ones, but there are few where I can't be sure or have to see the insides.

I have no real time scanner and sometimes run Malwarebytes.

Comment: Actually I think this is a valid question. I seem to recall that there is some Windows malware that **will** infect your PC by just opening up an email. Currently *I* am not aware of this on the Mac but as Mike Scott points out that doesn't mean it isn't out there or even possible.

Answer (score 1):

*Can* it be dangerous? Absolutely it can, there might be an unpatched vulnerability in the Mail app. But no one can tell you if such a vulnerability actually exists, because if it was known then it would already have been patched.